# dtatgridview is not clearing up?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have searched all through the web and still cannot find the right way to clear up my datagidview for the update. It maybe because I put two datagrid view in one windows form, I don't know. Though it worked, I mean it cleared up the datasource, before I added the new datagridview.

Can anyone please help me find the solution to refresh the datagridview? I also did used the  datagridview.datasource.refresh(). But it still the same?
Any Help or lead to the solution is very much appreciated, Thanks.

my code to clear the datagridview is :

```
        least30.DataSource = Nothing
        least30.CancelEdit()
        least30.EndEdit()
        least30.Columns.Clear()
        least30.Rows.Clear()

        mysqlcon.ConnectionString = "server =" + srvr + ";" + "user id =" + usrnm + ";" + "password =" + pswd + ";" + "database =" + dtb

        mysqlcon.Open()
        mysqlcmd.Connection = mysqlcon
        mysqlcmd.CommandText = "select " & "itm" & ", sum( " & "count" & " ) from " & "dtb.tbl" & " group by " & "itm" & " order by sum( " & "count" & " ) asc limit 40"
        mysqlrd = mysqlcmd.ExecuteReader
        mysqldt.Load(mysqlrd)

        least30.DataSource = mysqldt
        mysqlrd.Close()
        mysqlcon.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a data adapter. You call `Fill` on the data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and you bind that to the grid, preferably via a `BindingSource`. The user makes all the changes they want via the grid. You then call `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` to ensure that any pending change is committed and then `Update` on the data adapter to save the changes from the `DataTable` back to the database. Obviously you need to populate the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` of the data adapter to save changes of those types.

Here's a quick example:

```vb
Private adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Private table As DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder With
                    {
                        .DataSource = "MachineName\InstanceName",
                        .InitialCatalog = "DatabaseName",
                        .IntegratedSecurity = True
                    }
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString)

    Dim insertCommand As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SomeTable (SomeColumn) VALUES @SomeColumn", connection)
    Dim updateCommand As New SqlCommand("UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeColumn = @SomeColumn WHERE Id = @Id", connection)
    Dim deleteCommand As New SqlCommand("DELETE SomeTable WHERE Id = @Id", connection)

    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SomeColumn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "SomeColumn")

    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@SomeColumn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "SomeColumn")
    updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id")

    deleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id")

    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", connection) With
                {
                    .InsertCommand = insertCommand,
                    .UpdateCommand = updateCommand,
                    .DeleteCommand = deleteCommand
                }

    table = New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(table)
    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Validate()
    BindingSource1.EndEdit()
    adapter.Update(table)
End Sub
```

That code is written for SQL Server but it will be almost identical for MySQL. Just change all the `System.Data.SqlClient` types to the corresponding `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` types, e.g. `SqlConnection` to `MySqlConnection`. You would have to make some minor adjustments to the construction of the connection string and you'll need to change the SQL code and parameters to match your data but the principles all remain exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. But I just found out where the problem was.
Instead of trying to clear the rows and column with 
"least30.columns.clear()" and "least30.rows.clear()" 
I tried again with the "mysqldt.clear()" and my prblem was gone.
mysqldt is what holds the data actually.
Thanks, anyway, Sir!
I do appreciate your help.
Thanks